Android Studio Setup
I am experiencing an issue with Android Studio where the download progress is not being displayed. Despite waiting for over 20 minutes, the status remains stuck on “Preparing,” and no progress bar or percentage is shown. This makes it difficult to determine if the download is proceeding or if it has stalled. I have verified my internet connection and restarted Android Studio, but the problem persists


This is bug in android studio to not show downloading progress in the current update. I did also install this in my computer on last weekend.
it take some time to download 1.5GB file. Maybe your internet is slow that's why it's taking to much time. anyway leave as it is on waiting within more couple minutes it will done automatically as the file is downloaded on background.

i download it manually now its okay but when the emulator folder/file i download manually is not recognizing it keeps creating emulator-2 folder and downloading again

Just give it time; Depending on your download speed it could take a while.
It once took ~1 hour to do so for me.
Very annoying that there's no progress indicator.
Just grab a cup of tea and do something else in the meantime...

Thank you bro, done downloading i just slep then when i woke up it's done.

Please, Just be patient; the process can take some time depending on your internet speed. I once experienced a download that took almost two hour. It’s a bit inconvenient without any way to track the progress.
